# SQL query to extract a number from a text

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I need to extract a number from the content of a column. The column contains some adress data and a number.

For example:

```
Col X
-----
Address ABCD 9889030292
adress OPQR
9834347473
ADDR HIJK 2382982381
3, AST STREET, 4545009234
BNG 3483472234
```

Desired output:

```
Col Result
----------
9889030292
9834347473
2382982381
4545009234
3483472234
```

Which SQL query achieves this?

Answer (score 0):

This is for Oracle. I think this works in MS SQL Server also.

```
select upper(address) address, 
trim(both from translate(upper(address),'!~@#$%^&*()`1234567890-=_+[]{};"/?.>,<',' ')) characters,
trim(both from translate(upper(address),'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ@#$%^&*();":[]{},.<>/?',' ')) numbers
from (
select 'Col X' address from dual
union all
select 'Address ABCD 9889030292' from dual
union all
select 'adress OPQR' from dual
union all
select '9834347473' from dual
union all
select 'ADDR HIJK 2382982381' from dual
union all
select '3, ast street, 4545009234' from dual
union all
select 'BNG 3483472234' from dual);
```